# Check for WPS support in code

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I see that `WifiManager` has tools to initiate a WPS connection with a Wi-Fi network, but I see nothing that could actually check if WPS is available or not.

So, how to check if the current Wi-Fi network supports WPS?

Comment: So why did you vote this down? I still don't see any answer so it's not obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScanResult` has `capabilities` ([doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#capabilities)) field that contains the info:

example values:

```
[WPA-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][WPA2-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][WPS][ESS]
[WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]
```

or without

```
[WPA-PSK-TKIP][ESS]
[WPA-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][WPA2-PSK-TKIP+CCMP-preauth][ESS]
```

Comment: Yeah I used currentWiFiScanRes.capabilities.contains("WPS") and it works fine